# Why doesn't my query return any results?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join, outer-join

Why does this sql query only show results if they only have a row in users_warnings?

```
SELECT 
 u.id, 
 uw.warning 
FROM 
 users u
 INNER JOIN users_warnings uw ON (
  u.id = uw.uID
 )
LIMIT 21
```

I wish to show all users, but also grab the column "warning" in users_warnings, if any.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An `INNER JOIN` only returns something if there is data in both tables.
Try a `LEFT JOIN` instead:

```
SELECT u.id, uw.warning FROM users u
            LEFT JOIN users_warnings uw ON (u.id = uw.uID)
            LIMIT 21
```

Comment: This is more likley what you want rather than a outer join

Answer (score 6):

Because you're using an `inner join`, which requires a row to exist on the joined table. Try the following:

```
SELECT 
 u.id, 
 uw.warning 
FROM 
 users u
 LEFT JOIN users_warnings uw ON (
  u.id = uw.uID
 )
LIMIT 21
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your inner join for a left join, as so:

```
SELECT u.id, uw.warning FROM users u
                LEFT JOIN users_warnings uw ON (u.id = uw.uID)
                LIMIT 21
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  
    u.id,  
    IFNULL(uw.warning,'') warning
FROM  
   (SELECT id FROM users LIMIT 21) u 
   LEFT JOIN users_warnings uw
   ON u.id = uw.uID 
;
```

- Should be a LEFT JOIN not INNER JOIN
- Refactored the query to get first 21 users before attempting a JOIN (faster query)
- Defaulted warning to blank string if user had no warning